# R Plotting Error

Tags: r, plot

I have a frequency table named ft that looks like such:

```
ft <- table(scan("list_of_ints.txt"))
ft
     1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11 
621266 496647 436229 394595 353249 305882 253983 199455 147380 102872  67255 
    12     13     14     15     16     17     18     19     20     21     22 
 41934  24506  13778   7179   3646   1778    816    436    217    114     74 
    23     24     25    
    49     44     26
```

And I am trying to just plot a simple line graph with custom axis x-axis (1:25) and y-axis (1:1000000) by increments of powers of 10, with the following code:

```
plot(ft, type="b", log="y", axes=FALSE, ylim=c(1,10^7), xlim=c(1:25),
axis(2, at=10^(0:6), labels=formatC(10^(0:6), format="f", digits=0),
cex.axis=0.8, las=2), axis(1, at=1:25, cex.axis=.6))
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

How can the x and y lengths differ when there are 25 numbers and 25 corresponding frequency values being plotted??

Am I missing something here:/

Comment: There was a bunch of errors in your code, like mismatched parentheses and wrong format of `xlim`. Don't know how you got it to run in the first place but it works just fine now.

Comment: @Backlin Let's try to not _fix_ errors in code when editing; the errors might be the source of the problem, and it becomes extremely confusing for people trying to help (and the OP) if we just start making "fixes" to the code, rather than just adjusting the formatting.

Comment: Sorry, thought people would see it and also vote to close the question.

Comment: @Backlin No worries! I agree completely that we need some clarification from the OP, given the state of the code they provided. If you think your code fixes constitute a solution to their problem, you can always add it as an answer...

Comment: There are no mismatched parentheses, you can check yourself, and this is done in a command line terminal, so everything is encompassed within plot()

Comment: @Sean Your attempt to put everything inside of `plot` is incorrect, and it what Backlin meant by mismatched parens. `plot` and `axis` are separate commands.

Comment: ...but when I run this code as is, I do not get the error you get, so I think you need to clarify what exactly you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think people were assuming you had mismatched parenthesis because you inappropriately placed calls to `axis` inside the `plot` command. Those should be calls to separate functions.

```
plot(ft, type="b", log="y", axes=FALSE, ylim=c(1,10^7), xlim=c(1,25))
axis(2, at=10^(0:6), labels=formatC(10^(0:6), format="f", digits=0), cex.axis=0.8, las=2)
axis(1, at=1:25, cex.axis=.6)
```

Also i get an error about the `xlim`. The `xlim` parameter should be a vector with two values, the low and high value. I changed it to `xlim=c(1,25)`

Comment: My error lied in the fact that I included the axis commands within the plot() command.  My stupid mistake, but your answer works perfectly so thank you!